# XMLStarlet does not print full line

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have a problem with my batch. XMLStarlet does not show me the complete line.

However, I get with the batch file below only `3DS` and the rest of the line is not shown.

Output should be only the version information from first `title` tag line containing **3DS** in XML file, e.g. **9.4.0-21** without **3DS**.

I would be very glad about any answer.

My batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo.
echo ----------- Nintendo 3DS Firmware Checker --------------------------------------
echo --------------------- A CMD based Tool -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
httpget http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/feed.php nintendo3dsupdate.xml
for /f %%i in ('XML.EXE sel -t -v "//channel/item/title" "nintendo3dsupdate.xml"') do set "var111=%%i" >nul
echo.
echo.
echo                "%var111%" is the currently 3ds firmware.
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
```

The content of the XML file **nintendo3dsupdate.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/">
    <channel>
      <title>Sysupdate Reports</title>
      <atom:link href="http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/feed.php" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
      <link>http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php</link>
      <description>Nintendo System Update Reports</description>
      <lastBuildDate>Thu, 11 Dec 2014 23:05:04 +0000</lastBuildDate>
      <language>en</language>
      <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
      <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
        <item>
        <title>3DS 9.4.0-21</title>
        <link><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-11-14_07-05-04&sys=ctr]]></link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-11-14_07-05-04&sys=ctr]]></guid>
        <description>3DS 9.4.0-21</description>
        <pubDate>Thu, 11 Dec 2014 23:05:04 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage5)</title>
        <link><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-45-04&sys=ctr]]></link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-45-04&sys=ctr]]></guid>
        <description>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage5)</description>
        <pubDate>Mon, 08 Dec 2014 23:45:03 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage4)</title>
        <link><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-35-04&sys=ctr]]></link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-35-04&sys=ctr]]></guid>
        <description>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage4)</description>
        <pubDate>Mon, 08 Dec 2014 23:35:03 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage3)</title>
        <link><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-25-04&sys=ctr]]></link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/reports.php?date=12-08-14_07-25-04&sys=ctr]]></guid>
        <description>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage3)</description>
        <pubDate>Mon, 08 Dec 2014 23:25:04 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

The indents are with horizontal tab characters. There are 2 tabs left to `<title>3DS 9.4.0-21</title>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the batch code to get version information from first **title** tag starting with **3DS** from XML file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
echo(
echo(
echo ----------- Nintendo 3DS Firmware Checker --------------------------------------
echo --------------------- A CMD based Tool -----------------------------------------
echo(
echo(
echo(
del "%TEMP%\nintendo3dsupdate.xml" >nul 2>nul
set "FirmwareVersion3DS="
httpget http://yls8.mtheall.com/ninupdates/feed.php "%TEMP%\nintendo3dsupdate.xml"
for /F "tokens=3 delims=< " %%V in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "<title>3DS" "%TEMP%\nintendo3dsupdate.xml" 2^>nul') do (
    set "FirmwareVersion3DS=%%V"
    goto OutputInfo
)
echo Failed to determine version of 3DS firmware!
echo(
goto EndBatch

:OutputInfo
echo(
echo(
echo                "%FirmwareVersion3DS%" is the current 3DS firmware.
echo(
echo(
set FirmwareVersion3DS=

:EndBatch
del "%TEMP%\nintendo3dsupdate.xml" >nul 2>nul
endlocal
pause
```

The XML file is parsed first by command [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) searching for simple text string `<title>3DS` returning

```xml
        <title>3DS 9.4.0-21</title>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage5)</title>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage4)</title>
        <title>3DS 9.3.0-21 (stage3)</title>
```

Those four lines each indented with two horizontal tabs are redirected directly to command [for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) which splits each line using left angle bracket and space character as delimiter. Therefore first line is split to:

- token 1:                  (two horizontal tabs)
- token 2: `title>3DS`
- token 3: `9.4.0-21`
- token 4: `/title>`

As just the version number is of interest, just token **3** is assigned to loop variable **V** assigned next to the environment variable **FirmwareVersion3DS**.

For this task just the first line with a version information is of interest. The loop is exited therefore with a jump to output the found version information after processing the first line returned by command **findstr**.

An error message is output instead of the version information if an error occurred like no XML file because of no connection to web server, or syntax in XML file changed in the meantime.

There is no check made if third token is really referencing the version information. Therefore the batch file code must be updated if for example spaces instead of tabs are output by the PHP script on server for indenting the lines.

The batch code deletes the XML file before downloading it from server to avoid parsing an old XML file. The XML file and the used environment variable are also deleted before exiting the batch file just for leaving a clean environment back.

---

**EDIT:**

The line with command **for** could be also

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=<    " %%V in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "<title>3DS" "nintendo3dsupdate.xml" 2^>nul') do (
```

There are three characters after `delims=`:

1. an angle bracket `<` and
2. a horizontal tab character *(not a sequence of spaces as browser displays)* and
3. a single space character.

The order of the delimiter characters is important as otherwise command line interpreter would exit batch script because of a syntax error.

The indenting tabs are ignored with this modification. Now the first line is split for that reason to:

- token 1: `title>3DS`
- token 2: `9.4.0-21`
- token 3: `/title>`

And token **2** instead of 3 contains now the string of interest to output.

This solution is better than first one as it does not matter anymore if the line with the version string is indented with spaces or tabs or not indented at all.